# Combinar dos registros de una tabla con un registro de otra

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Soy novato en esto de la programación (estoy en formación) fíjense lo siguiente esperando su ayuda y aclaratorias.

Mi sistema funciona de la siguiente manera:

1ra. tabla `participante`, donde almaceno datos básicos del estudiante, nombres, apellidos, cédulas, fecha de inscripción

2da. tabla `participante_has_trabajo` donde relaciono el `Id` del `Participante` con el id del `trabajo`

3ra. tabla `trabajo` donde almaceno el nombre del trabajo y los datos únicos de ambos participantes como carrera, mención, núcleo, el Id de la fecha en que se registro ya que esta es la que me permitirá ubicar los registros que quiero.

realizo la consulta a la base de datos de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * FROM  participante_has_trabajo 
inner join participante on participante_has_trabajo.participante_ipte = participante.ipte 
inner join trabajo on participante_has_trabajo.trabajo_id = trabajo.id  
inner join fecha_hora on trabajo.fecha_hora_idf = fecha_hora.idf 
inner join nucleo on trabajo.nucleo_idn = nucleo.idn 
inner join mencion on trabajo.mencion_idm = mencion.idm 
inner join carrera on mencion.carrera_idc = carrera.idc 
where fecha BETWEEN '2018-08-06' and '2018-08-06' ORDER BY trabajo.id
```

Si tengo dos participante asociados a un `trabajo_id`, en la tabla participante_has_trabajo me trae los datos pero como registros individuales

[image: consulta de registros]
lo que quiero hacer es, en el caso de que un trabajo tenga dos participantes asociados como haría para unir esos dos participantes a un solo titulo de trabajo

agradezco su ayuda un saludo...

Comment: Tendrías que agrupar por la columna `id` de la tabla `trabajo`, algo así: `... GROUP BY trabajo.id ORDER BY trabajo.id `. **PERO** hay otra cosa muy importante: debes decidir cuáles son las columnas que necesitas. El  `SELECT *`  no conviene para este tipo de consulta (ni para ninguna otra). Aquí debes saber lo que hay que hacer con las columnas que serían repetidas y que van a venir agrupadas. Por ejemplo, todas las columnas de `participantes` estarán en esa situación, debes decidir cuáles quieres, si quieres alguna e indicar en la consulta cómo se agruparán, usando por ej. `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de como esperas que sea el resultado deseado, y para que lo vas a ocupar, para poder ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: hola gracias por responder :) bien, si te fijas en la imagen, en la columna nombretrabajo, hay tres registros de los cuales dos de ellos son iguales ( son los títulos de los Trabajos los cuales tiene un ID) en la columna de pnombre (primer nombre del participante)  todos son distintos. el resultado que quiero obtener seria el siguiente: // titulo: LA SENSIBILIDAD ORGANIZACIONAL EN LA.... participantes: IVOR - Andrea //

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es como has dicho en el comentario:

> El resultado que quiero obtener seria el siguiente:
>
> ```
> titulo                                          participantes
> -----------------------------------------------------------------
> LA SENSIBILIDAD ORGANIZACIONAL EN LA....        IVOR - Andrea
> ```

Puedes obtener los datos que esperas del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT 
    t.nombretrabajo, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.pnombre SEPARATOR ' - ') participantes
FROM  participante_has_trabajo pht
    INNER JOIN participante p   ON   pht.participante_ipte = p.ipte 
    INNER JOIN trabajo t        ON   pht.trabajo_id = t.id  
    INNER JOIN fecha_hora fh    ON   t.fecha_hora_idf = fh.idf 
    INNER JOIN nucleo n         ON   t.nucleo_idn = n.idn 
    INNER JOIN mencion m        ON   t.mencion_idm = m.idm 
    INNER JOIN carrera c        ON   m.carrera_idc = c.idc 
WHERE f.fecha BETWEEN '2018-08-06' AND '2018-08-06' 
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.id;
```

Las claves aquí son:

- que agrupas por cada columna `id` de la tabla `trabajo`
- que agrupas con un separador las filas que serían repetidas en cuanto al nombre del participante, usando la función de agrupación `GROUP_CONCAT`

He usados alias cortos en las tablas, para escribir una consulta menos *verbosa* y más fácil de analizar. Es una práctica extendida usar la primera letra o las iniciales de cada tabla como alias.

Answer (score 0):

probé la sentencia que me indicaste... y efectivamente funciono (aprendi algo nuevo) :D

excelente el resultado, solo que cuando incluya los datos tendré que colocar espacios en cada input después de los datos

(en el resultado de la sentencia aparecen los datos del participante juntos **(cuadro de color verde)** y se separa con el "-" del otro participante, quisiera que quedara como el que esta en el cuadro de color azul (vale destacar que los datos que están en el cuadro azul ya vienen con espacios desde la base de datos 
 yo haciendo pruebas) que tendría que añadirle a la sentencia? anexo print.

[image: Resultados de la consulta]

ultima pregunta...
en caso que quiera un segundo `group_concat` en la misma sentencia, como haría en ese caso?

les estoy muy agradecido por toda la ayuda... tenia dos días tratando :D

Comment: No entiendo bien esta nueva situación que planteas. Parece que hay un problema con la manera en que guardas los datos. De ser así, eso no se debe resolver en la consulta sino que deberías corregir los datos en sí. Como quiera que sea, Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas. Creo que cualquier otra duda, aunque sea sobre el mismo código, debes plantearla en una nueva pregunta.