# dos consultas en una sola tabla uno a la par de la otra

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema de la consulta siguiente

```
SELECT ncuenta,dcuenta,sum(saldo)as saldo,fiscal 
FROM cap_tmp_eladi where fiscal='2017-2018' GROUP BY ncuenta union 
select ncuenta,dcuenta,sum(saldo)as saldo,fiscal 
from cap_tmp_eladi where fiscal='2018-2019' GROUP BY ncuenta
```

De esta manera me muestra los datos que quiero hacia abajo pero, quisiera que esa misma consulta este una a la par de la otra. De esta manera

```
<consulta 1>                                    <consulta2>
```

Comment: Podrías usar `GROUP_CONCAT`, [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/186791/29967).

Comment: Tambien `UNION` podria funcionar, siempre y cuando la cantidad de datos sea la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría usar una sub busqueda:

SELECT ncuenta,dcuenta,sum(saldo)as saldo,fiscal,(select sum(b.saldo) from cap_tmp_eladi b where b.fiscal='2018-2019' and b.ncuenta=a.ncuenta GROUP BY ncuenta) as SaldoTabla2 FROM cap_tmp_eladi a where fiscal='2017-2018' GROUP BY ncuenta union

Comment: podria ser, pero quisiera algo como así tal vez de esta manera solo que la tabla t2 no se comporta como quisiera SELECT t1.ncuenta,t1.dcuenta,t1.saldo,t1.fiscal,t2.ncuenta,t2.dcuenta,t2.saldo,t2.fiscal
from 
(SELECT ncuenta,dcuenta,sum(saldo)as saldo,fiscal FROM cap_tmp_eladi where fiscal='2017-2018' GROUP BY ncuenta) as t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ncuenta,dcuenta,sum(saldo)as saldo,fiscal from cap_tmp_eladi where fiscal='2018-2019' GROUP BY ncuenta) as t2